# Ajax web service request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I've been given access to a web service that will return data back in xml format.  I'm getting one of two errors:  Cross origin domain error and now this new error - refuse to execute script from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.  Using web services is new to me so this is only second time I've worked with one.

The corss origin error I downloaded and used the plugin `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ajax-cross-origin.min.js"></script>` which lead me to the second error of refusing to run script.

Here is the code:

```
            $.ajax({                                         
            type:"GET",                
            url: "xxxx://xxxxx/xxxxx/Service.asmx/GetParts?productSeriesId=165126&langId=EN&skipAttributes=Y",                
            dataType: "xml",
            crossOrigin: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d)
            },
            error: function() {                                       
                console.log("error!");
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is an image of the refusal error

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cross origin domain error

You are trying to use XMLHttpRequest.

This error means that the web service does not allow your site to instruct your visitor's browser to request data from it using the visitor's credentials (this it the default state).

> refuse to execute script from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

You are trying to use JSONP.

JSONP is a hack to bypass the security policy mentioned above (it predates CORS which is the standard way to control that policy). You are trying to use it and the browser is falling over because the site isn't responding with a JSONP program.

---

You either need to change the web service to support CORS or JSONP or you need to fetch the data using server side code (e.g. a proxy).

Comment: well looks like it will be the proxy route because I dont have access to the service to make any changes